# Windows Authentication using Selenium Grid and Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I was asked a question :

Assume I have **4 machines** and I need to execute a script in all the machines across all the browsers. How will I achieve that.

I told him the concept of Selenium Grid, where in we could set up a machine which acts like a hub, configure 3 more machines which would act like a node. 
Using `Desired Capabilities` among others we could choose a browser type and version type in that and write a script.

But he asked me two things :

1. IN all the node **machines** how do you configure the **Windows username and Password** if the machine is locked. Can you write windows **Authentication** in the script.
2. Can I achieve testing different **browser versions** of same browser type in a single node?
3. Can I pass as a the **browser type and browser version** as a parameter 
   from hub to the node?

Can someone throw some light on these as I was unable to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: Is it really necessary for the machine to be unlocked for the test to start? The selenium node is a background process that listens for commands, and executes them on the browser, so I do not think this is necessary. If it is necessary due to your specific windows settings however, then no, you cannot do this from the selenium script obviously.

Question 2: Yes, you can test different browser versions of the same type on the same node. You can pass the browser name and version to the node. *However, keep in mind that the node cannot know the location of the different browser versions, so you will also have to supply the path to the browser executable for your requested version*